# Is there a KLT Fano variety with a normal anticanonical element?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ whose anticanonical divisor $-K_X$ is ample $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier. 
Assume that $X$ has only KLT singularities but **not canonical**.

**Question** Is there an example of $X$ such that the anticanonical system $|{-}K_X|$ contains a normal element $D$? Or, if $D$ exists, is it always non-normal?

By adjunction, $D$ is not canonical but Gorenstein. 
If $\dim X =2$, I think $D$ is non-normal by the adjunction reason since $D$ is singular then non-normal.

I want to know the cases $\dim X \ge 3$ or $=3$ in particular.

Sorry, it seems that $\mathbb{P}(1,1,1,n)$ is a typical example. 
I will perhaps close this question.

Comment: Do you know what happens for toric varieties?  For example, is $|-K_X|$ ever base point free for KLT but not canonical toric varieties?

Comment: Actually, I don't know it for toric varieties. I expect that there is a toric example with normal elements, but I can't find it. Such KLT Fano varieties are non-Gorenstein and their anticanonical element should pass through non-Gorenstein locus, so they have base locus.

Comment: taronaso, you are right of course.  So if one can show that the base locus is sufficiently small dimensional...